# Using SQS with the multiple same lambda consumers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm using a Lambda as a consumer to poll the messages from a SQS queue. Because of the lambda scaling mechanism, my Lambda functions won't be scale-up as fast/many as possible, even if there are many visible messages in the queue. For example, there are about 30,000 message in my queue, the lambda concurrency execution is 40. That means only 40 lambda function instances were processing the message. Increasing the batch size doesn't help a lot. I think the bottleneck is Lambda scaling/polling, but I can't control it.

If I setup more identical Lambda consumers (do the same thing) to poll the messages (like the picture below), the messages might be consumed faster than only one Lambda consumer does. In my case, I need at most 3 Lambda consumers to achieve the ideal performance. However, I haven't seen any practices like this.
Is it a good practice?

[image]

Comment: That is certainly not good practice. Are you really having such large peak traffic that lambda does not scale up immediately and the automatic scale up takes too long?

Comment: My producer (another lambda) generates <10000 messages at a time. My consumer might not be able to process messages as quick as they are produced

Comment: "at a time" meaning once or every second from then on? What does your consumer manage to consume? Is it *that* problematic if the lambda takes a bit to scale up? What is your target time to process all messages? Etc.

Comment: "at a time" means one user request. One user request generates thousands of message. Every message stands for a s3 object upload operation. My consumer uploads s3 objects from a bucket to another bucket. The faster consumer process messages, the faster users to get responses. I hope a process can be done in 5 seconds.

Comment: One bucket stores tar files, another bucket stores raw files. So, a user request just like a untar command. If there are 10000 files in a tar file, there are 10000 messages will be produced in my queue for each file creation event

Comment: Use on-demand EC2s might solve the performance problem. However, the EC2s might be  over-provisioned during off-peak time.

Comment: Should I leverage Kinesis instead of SQS?

Comment: I am quite sure you can have more than 40 concurrent executions. Please check the link below and request limit increase if it is required. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html

Comment: @Azize, From this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling), it said "... Lambda increases the number of processes that are reading batches by up to 60 more instances per minute". I think this is the reason why my lambda instances cannot be scaled up too much, right?

Comment: Ask AWS support how to make your lambda scale up higher and faster. They will check your limits and other lambdas that can be impacting.

Comment: Thanks you all! I learn a lot from your advice. I decide to modify the request workflow.